# Error trying to plot an ols object in R

Tags: r, plot, rms

I'm currently having issues trying to plot a linear regression done with ols() in R.

My code is:

```
library(languageR)
library(rms)

english.dd = datadist(english)

options(datadist = "english.dd")

english.ols = ols(RTlexdec  ~ WrittenFrequency + LengthInLetters, english)

plot(english.ols)

## Error en match.arg(type) : 
##   'arg' should be one of “ordinary”, “score”, “dfbeta”, “dfbetas”, “dffit”,  “dffits”, “hat”, “hscore”

## Calls: plot ... weighted.residuals -> residuals -> residuals.ols -> match.arg
```

I don't know how to resolve the problem, I've been looking for solutions online but I couldn't find any.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you expect in your plot?

Answer (score 1):

When I run

```
plot(Predict(english.ols))
```

I get:
[image]

There are many other examples in `?plot.Predict`

Comment: I don't need to plot the Predict(), that one works well, I need to plot the regression model that shows how each predictor influence the dependent variable.

Comment: I don't follow. It seems like the plot I show above shows the estimate of the effect of each predictor on the dependent variable, with confidence bound. Do you want to see the diagnositic plots of residuals vs fitted? rediduals vs normal curve?

Comment: I was wrong, I'm sorry, that's exactly what I needed :) Thank you very much.